# TFS 2015 Build Agent Not running builds

Tags: build, tfs-2015

Our company is upgrading from TFS 2013 to TFS 2015. We have set up the XAML Builds to work without any issues. now we want to start using the new process in 2015. We ave set up the build agents on a build server. When we queue up a build it fails without any reason why. The build when queued just states "Waiting for an available agent" for 2 minutes then fails. It seems like The build agent can't be connected to. We have made the service account running the build agent as System Admin on the Windows 2012 Server. I've added a pre-build step that updates a build version and the seems to be working as the first step. is there any diagnostic logs I can view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We figured out the issue. Somehow the folder permissions were not set correctly. so we removed permissions and reapplied which solved the issue.

Comment: Permissions to what folder?

Answer (score 0):

First,please double check the step and **configuration of your build agent** following this tutorial: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) After doing this, your vnext build agent pool and agent should all be **green**.

Make sure in your build definition you have select the right agent queue. Also try to create an **empty build definition with no build task** to see if the issue is related to the definition. And also restart your agent service on your TFS server.

Also check if the service ***[Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252450(v=vs.120).aspx)*** is running. If not, start it manually and try the build again.

[image]

*Note: The servie is running in TFS server, not build server.*

For **logs** to troubleshooting , check the ***event view*** and  the log in `\agent_diag` on build agent to see whether there are some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account that the agent is running under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role (`http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool`).

[image]

If adding the account to Agent Pool Service Account still doesn't work, try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work.